# Django Tutorial Templates without head, body and Doctype?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm just wondering, wether it is the right/recommended way to omit the Doctype, head und body tags? Because at least the Django tutorial does it, as can be seen in [tutorial 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/), 
in the polls/templates/polls/index.html:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The tutorial code contains examples. They are kept brief and minimal since it's assumed that learners already know html, and there are many other references available about how to structure html documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include all the required tags. As on the tutorials they remove so that you can focus on the key point rather then the usual tags. Don't omit the required tags on your work. For learning you can.